# Prove uniform boundedness of probability density function of averaged i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with probability density function $f(x)$ uniformly bounded by a constant $B$. Now I want to show, the averaged $\bar{X}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\bar{X}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}
also has probability density function uniformly bounded by some constant which is independent of n.
By central limit theorem we know it converges to standard normal distribution, so seem this should be true, however I couldn’t prove it by simple inductive argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1954 book *Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables* by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov gives , in section 46, "Limit Theorem for Densities", a sufficient condition for the  the central limit theorem to hold for densities: if some convolution product of the density is in an $L^r$ space, for some $r\in(1,2]$, the desired convergence holds.

In the case at hand, $r=2$ suffices: if $f$ is bounded by $B$ then $\int f^2 \le B\int f = B<\infty$, so $f\in L^2$ and the convergence holds.

Ibragimov and Linnik's 1971 [*Independent and stationary sequences of random variables*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/independent-and-stationary-sequences-of-random-variables/oclc/476327472) has a straightforward proof.

See also Bhattacharya and Rao, *Normal Approximation and Asymptotic Expansions*, section 19, for a vector version of this result.

Thanks to antkam for finding a big mistake in an earlier version of this post.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious...  What is the support / range of $x$ in your example?  $p(0) \to \infty$ if my intuition is correct...

Comment: @antkam  You are right.  Nice catch.  G&K's $p$ is unbounded at the origin.  I'll rewrite my post asap!

Comment: my username is "antkam", not "antikam".  "antikam" = "anti-kam" would be my evil twin ;)

Comment: @antkam  Whoops!  Sorry; fixed.  Not a very good day for accuracy for me, I guess.

Comment: I've had _lots_ of those days, believe me... it got so bad I now have a hard rule never to post on MSE early in the morning.  So dont worry, you're not alone.  :)  Anyway instead of quoting a 1954 book, by Kolmogorov of all people, is there a simpler proof, that works for this specific example?  Proving $\sum X_i$ bounded is easy (by convolution) but $\sum X_i / \sqrt{n}$ makes it non-trivial.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!